# Should Session be checked on Page Load in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, session

Page Load, as a sentence of 2 words, means when the page is loaded, means, when all elements are loaded.

Let's say I have a page called `Ask.aspx`, and this page is only allowed to users who have signed in, so technically I would write something like this :

```
if(Session["id"]==null)
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

This mean, that I'm testing the Session AFTER the page loads, theoretically, I think it sounds wrong, now of course I won't notice it, it will be fast, I will try to access the page, then I'm redirected to Login.aspx, but... is it correct to test the Session on Page Load method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Page_Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#lifecycle_events) is part of the page lifecycle. It is called when the ***Server*** loads the page, not when the *Client* loads the page...

So this *is* the correct place to check the Session Variable...

You're actually saying: *Before I post the page back to the client, check if I have the `ID` property set for this session... If I don't - tell the client to redirect to the Login.aspx page...*

This is the correct way of doing this...

I recommened you also read about [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). The difference between it and `Response.Redirect` is that in `Server.Transfer` the server itself "redirects" to another page and outputs the result of the new page back to the client (without the client knowing about it).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to limit access to specific pages, you would be better off using forms authentication.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

It is fairly easy to setup and it allows checking of credentials before the request is passed to the asp.net pipeline. In what you are doing, your page goes through the entire lifecycle (controls are rendred and bound to data, access to database, calls to web services etc.) before the request is rejected. Depending on your situation, this might be costly and will not scale well.

**Edit:** You can also hook in to the `AcquireRequestState` event in the global.asax. This will also spare the entire page life cycle.